# How can I receive a notification every time someone sign up through my MailChimp form?

Tags: mailchimp

I would like to receive an email every time someone signs up through my mailchimp form.
Is there any way to do that?
If not, are there any other email automation services which offer this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. But this is a MailChimp setting question (not one for StackOverflow).

You can do this by going to the website -> Audience -> Manage Audience -> Settings -> Audience Name and Defaults -> Add your email to the "New subscriber notifications" section.

You may need admin permissions for this.